# Magento Product "Custom Options" Percentage

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

My Magento store is running 1.9.1.0. All of the products within my store have a default price of $0.00 because the price is determined from "custom options" that are selected within a product's page.

Although, one of my "custom options" for a product is based from 15% of the entire product's price. For some reason, it does not work. I am assuming that it does not work because the default product's price is $0.00 and it does not take the price after all of the custom options have been selected into consideration.

I would like some guidance on how I can make it so that the "custom option" for 15% takes into account the full amount after all custom options have been selected.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is two way to do this work

**Way : 1**

If your Product Price is $0.00 and you want to change the Price 15% as per the option

then you can try the Group Product in Magento

here you have the base Product Price is depend on the Selected Products Price

**Way : 2**

You can create a attribute based on the Price like : tmp_price and put the product Price here and calculate the 15% of the Price of the option using the customization

let me know if can help more in this task